# whats the name of this windows phone 7 element?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

hi sometimes i get at the top of the screen a small message like: this is only a trial version, when i click on it, it get invisible.

what is the name of this form element? want to use it too

i think it is not a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it comes with an incredibly annoying sound, then it's a MessageBox.

It not, then it's maybe some kind of child window - see http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects

Answer (score 1):

Without any kind of visual reference it's difficult to tell, but you may be referring to a "Toast". There is no specific API in the current version of the framework, though the Mango tools for version 7.1 that are now available include the [`ShellToast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) method for this.

If you're developing a 7.0 app for the currently available devices then you can use the `ToastRequestTrigger` from the [Prism libraries for WP7](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com).